# 'None type' object has no attribute 'year'

Tags: django, python-2.7, datetime

I'm trying to get the year from a datetime form but I'm getting this error when I run the project code `'None type' object has no attribute 'year'` I've tried both `import datetime` and `from datetime import datetime` but with no success. Although in another function placed before this one in the same file views.py I wrote the same code (of year getting...) and it works very well!
PS: when I run the code on the ipdb shell it works correctly!
this the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
def My_function(request):
    data = tableA.find()
    dt = datetime.now()
    y = dt.year
    m = dt.month
    d = dt.day
    for i in data:
        if i['ma_date'].year == y:
             ma_liste.append([i["ma_date"])
return render(request, ma_page.html, ma_liste)
```

and this is the erreor

```
**AttributeError at /ma_page/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'year'**
```

Comment: Please show the actual code you are executing and a complete error stack trace.

Comment: done can you check it please

Comment: What is `tableA`? What is `data`? Have you tried logging the contents of `data` before the loop?

Comment: tableA is a collection from my mondb database and data contains what is in this collection , tableA.find() is equivalent to "select * from tableA" in sql. the data form is like this [{u'town': 'canada', u'ma_date': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 11, 00, 30, 1)}, {u'town': 'chicago', u'ma_date': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 8, 13, 32, 8)},{ u'town': 'california', u'ma_date': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 8, 13, 32, 10)}]

Comment: is there any way to transform ma_date from datetime.datetime() to datetime()

Comment: thank you everyone Isolved the problem

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with `datetime`. Your `data` item has no `year` attribute.

You haven't shown your code or a structure for this object, but it's likely it's just a multidimensional array, in which case you could use: `i['ma_date']['year']`.

Comment: i['ma_date'] gives this datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 12, 9, 30, 1) so I've tried import datetime then another error appears about datetime.now() so I changed to datetime.datetime.now() but unfortunately the first error appears again....

Comment: Also on the ipdb shell when I test i['ma_date'].year it shows me 2015! but the problem appears when I go to the page ma_page.html